# Are pointer to a member of this allowed in object initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, aggregate-initialization

From [Aggregate initialization, set pointer to struct member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190650/struct-initialization-set-pointer-to-struct-member#60190786), is the following code legal:

```
struct S 
{
  int a;
  int* aptr;
};

S s = { 3, &s.a };
```

Comment: I'd also be curious about whether analogous code is valid when the two members of `S` are in reversed order.

Comment: @JimOldfield I don't think order matters here. Since we're taking a pointer instead of the value itself we cannot run into trouble of reading an uninitialized value. The address of a member relative to it's class can't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from latest standard draft:

> [basic.scope.pdecl]
>
> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator ([dcl.decl]) and **before its initializer** (if any), except as noted below.

So, yes. The identifier `s` has already been declared, so it can be used in its initialiser.

Note that the value of `s` may not be used until it has been initialised. The value is not used in the example, so this is not a problem.

> I'd also be curious about whether analogous code is valid when the two members of S are in reversed order

The order of members does not matter.

Comment: I've got a query. Implementing a constructor will throw `warning: variable 's' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]`. Doesn't this make this illegal?

Comment: @theWiseBro The example in the question doesn't use the value of `s`.